# ASP.NET MVC 3. System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Help me please.
I have a asp.net mvc 3 application. I need to delete a file from server, but i can't. When i test my application on local machine - delete is successful, but when i run it on web server i have error System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
     ...
     if (ad.AdPhoto1 != null)
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Content/photos/" + ad.AdPhoto1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if it not open by some other application first. Because in most cases you get such an error when it is used by another app :)

Comment: Could you show the code that is creating this file? It looks like you have a leaking handle. That's where the problem is, not with deleting the file.

Comment: It's probably still being held by the WebDev.WebServer.exe file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not so full question, i had not so much time yesterday...
The file is image (for example . jpg). I have a model:

```
public class Ad
{
    public int AdId { get; set; }
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Photo")]
    public string AdPhoto1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Photo 2")]
    public string AdPhoto2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Photo 3")]
    public string AdPhoto3 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Photo 4")]
    public string AdPhoto4 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When i create a new "Ad" i upload Photo on server and write it's name to my model. How i doing this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Ad ad, int? Categories, int? SubCategories, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fotoUpload)
{
    ...
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int count = 1;
            foreach (var file in fotoUpload)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomItem = random.Next(1, 100);

                if (file != null)
                {
                    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Content/photos/";
                    string filename = randomItem + count + "Photo" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    if (Request.ContentLength > 1228800) 
                    {
                        ViewBag.FileSizeError = "Сумарный размер загружаемых вами файлов превышает ограничение в 1,2 МБ";
                        ModelState.Remove("Categories");
                        ValuteInitializer();
                        return View();
                    }

                    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));

                    switch (count)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            ad.AdPhoto1 = filename;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ad.AdPhoto2 = filename;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ad.AdPhoto3 = filename;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ad.AdPhoto4 = filename;
                            break;
                    }

                }

                count++;
            }
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                ad.AdAuthor = User.Identity.Name;
                ad.AdVisibility = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ad.AdData = DateTime.Now;
            ad.AdPriority = 3;
            ad.CategoryId = Categories;
            ad.SubCategoryId = SubCategories;
            db.Ads.Add(ad);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CreateSuccess");
        }

        return View(ad);
    }
```

I watch a lot of posts about the same problems but I have not found a solution to my problem. I guess the problem might be related to the streams, maybe. So, i hope that someone can help me...